# Converting Hexadecimal NUmbers in English ASCII characters

Tags: c, hex, ascii

In the below given code I am getting Hexa decimal values..i.e. `68 65 68 65`... I want to convert it into English alphabetical characters like `hehe`...

I am not able to convert the hexadecimal numbers obtained to their          English characters

```
printf("\nCommand: ");
for(i = 54; i<=57; i++)
{       
printf("%X", packet[i]);
printf(" ");
}
```

Prints `68 65 68 65` but I want `hehe`

Comment: You did not mention what language you are using. You should add it as a tag (like you did with smtp, hex and co) so that we can understand precisely what you want and provide a better help.

Comment: All numbers in your program are binary. Hex, ASCII etc are just various ways to display/format binary numbers. Therefore, "convert from hex to characters" doesn't make sense. You already have the data in binary format. You just need to display it as text, so your question boils down to "how to print characters". Which your C programming book answers early on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `%c`

```
printf("%c", packet[i]);
```

As `%X` will print the value as hexadecimal number. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score -2):

You can use below code to get Alphabet for a Number:

```
alphabet = printf("%c", Number);
```

Comment: this answer is not C